# why do i get 1 instead of the file required?

Tags: php, require

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [including php file from another server with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752783/including-php-file-from-another-server-with-php)

i want to have my own error system instead of having the php errors so for example i require a file from another server and that server is not available right now

```
<?php
require 'http://example.com/file.php' or die ("that host is not available right now");
?>
```

but instead i get

> Warning: require(1) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '1'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 5

Comment: This is a **very** bad idea if you aren't the administrator of `example.com`.

Comment: @Pablo No, that's not the cause of `require(1)`. The `1` is the question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `require 'foo' or bar()` is interpreted as `require ('foo' or bar())`. `'foo' or bar()` equals `true`, i.e. `1`. If you want to write it like this, use different parentheses:

```
(require 'http://example.com/file.php') or die ("that host is not available right now");
```

**But**, you don't need `die` at all here, since `require` will already halt program execution if the required file can't be loaded. Just `require 'http://example.com/file.php';` will do fine. Whether you should actually load foreign PHP files over the network is another story (hint: probably not).

Comment: (Responding to removed comment:) No, because `require` already stops program execution! There is nothing *after* a failed `require`. If you want custom error handling, override the error handler instead.

Comment: i'm sorry for the dumb question (my guess) how do i do this ?

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Use the include function instead (it doesn't throw a fatal error). And remember the precedence of operators.

Comment: @Jaison For one-off includes that's a good solution. For a global "custom error handler" he should override the error handler though.

Comment: @deceze I agree with you. But for a particular check, this gonna work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the precedence of operators. The PHP are including the result of the "or" comparison (true). Try to remove this.

```php
include('http://...') or die('error...');
```

It will work.

Comment: if i remove the or i get other errors

Comment: If you want to custom check your errors, use the include function instead of the require statement. And if you are getting errors, read the other answers. Turn on allow_url_include directive.