# separating Model folder, view folder and controller folder in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, project, directory-structure

can i place the model and view folders of the MVC structure of codeigniter to different location irrespective to the regular path

```
application/views
application/models
```

to some other location, lets say

```
abc/views
pqr/models
```

outside the project folder.
if possible then how can i achieve it.

thank you in advance

Comment: Try searching `HMVC Codeigniter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no feature to customize the `models` and `views` path in CodeIgniter current stable versions *(while in CI 3.x you can change the `view` path as well as `application` and `system`)*.

But you can load your files outside of the typical `views` and `models` folders.

The path to the file is relative. So you can use `../` to go one **UP** level in path.

For example, If the `abc` folder is placed near `application`, you should use `../../abc` to reach to that folder.

Take a look at the example below:

**Model:**

```
class Model_name extends CI_Model {

    public function baz($value='')
    {
        return $value;
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
class Foo extends CI_Controller {

    public function bar()
    {
        $this->load->model('../../pqr/models/model_name');

        $data['var'] = $this->model_name->baz('Yes It Works!');

        $this->load->view('../../abc/views/view_name', $data);
    }

}
```

**View:**

```
<?php echo $var; ?>
```

Here is the sample folder structure:

```
application
system
pqr
   /models
          /model_name.php
abc
   /views
         /view_name.php
```

---

*As a **Side-note**: Make sure direct accessing to the `pqr` or `abc` directories is restricted. add a `.htaccess` file inside them with the content of `Deny from all`.*

Comment: this solution is correct if placed on a single server. suppose if a developer is creating a controller on say `192.168.1.2/test/` and ist respective view is being made on say `192.168.1.3/xyz` what should i do for such a case. is it possible now

Comment: I highly recommend you to change your strategy, take a look [at here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752783/including-php-file-from-another-server-with-php) for further info.

Comment: i got ur concern. but i am planning to implement this only for development phase. i tried using the method stated in the link you gave of editing the php.ini file. still not working. i am calling the following way,
`$this->load->view('http:/ /192.168.1.3/t2/welcome_message');`

Comment: Because that is not the way `CI_Loader::view();` works. CI tries to include  view files from `APPPATH.'views/'` and lots of checks are done like `file_exists();` before including the view file. By the way, you can `include()` your files manually, but before that, `extract()` your passing `$data`.

Answer (score 1):

To customize models and views outside the 'application' folder, follow these easy steps,

- Create `My_Loader.php` file in 'application/core' directory
- Copy the following code into the custom `My_Loader.php`

  ```
  class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

  function mymodel($model, $folder = '',$vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {

      array_push($this->_ci_model_paths, "");
      parent::model($model);
  }


  function myview($folder, $view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {
          $this->_ci_view_paths = array_merge($this->_ci_view_paths, array(APPPATH . '../' . $folder . '/' => TRUE));
          return $this->_ci_load(array(
                  '_ci_view' => $view,
                  '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars),
                  '_ci_return' => $return
          ));
  }
  ```

  - Save the file and in the controller, call and load the model (which resides outside the application folder) as:

  `$this->load->mymodel('folder/model');`

and for the view,

```
$this->load->myview('views','view_dir/view-php-file', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no feature to customise the models and views path in CodeIgniter current stable versions (while in CI 3.x you can change the view path as well as application and system) by default.

But you can do this by changing it in file *{CI DIR}/system/core/Loader.php* and in the main *index.php* file.

Take a look at the example below:

Modify the file *Loader.php* in CI 3.x

The line 80 reads

```
protected $_ci_model_paths =    array(APPPATH);
```

Change it to

```
protected $_ci_model_paths =    array(MODELPATH);
```

And in the main *index.php* file, add

```
$model_folder = 'pqr';
```

and

```
define('MODELPATH', $model_folder);
```

to customise the views folder path, already given in CI 3.x

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can move views and models to different locations but you can change the location of application folder to the location of your choice.

You can move your application directory to different location and then open your  index.php file and set the $system_folder and $application_folder variables with the new path values, preferably with a full path, e.g. '/www/MyUser/system'.

Reference: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/index.html

Hope this is helpful.