# Which method is more secure/suitable for blocking access to a subdirectory using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to use `.htaccess` to block external access to my website's `/includes/` directory which only includes processing `PHP` files. Both methods below 'work' but *I prefer the latter* because it doesn't leave the user with a error page. Can anybody let me know if it is less secure?

Is it better to use this:

```
<Directory "/includes">
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Or this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/includes/.*$ http://www.mymainurl.com
```

Or is something else more appropriate?

The website content is dynamically served by an index.php, so files within the `/includes/` folder need to remain accessible via `PHP`'s include function.

Comment: The visitor who hits your /includes/ directory *deserves* an error message.  Although now that I think about it, "RedirectMatch" denies the bad guy information, which is good.

Comment: I tend to agree, however I want to make sure any faulty link doesn't scare off my users with a technical error message!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can return a 404 to make people think the includes directory doesn't even exist:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^includes/ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, combined with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]` and `ErrorDocument 404 /404`. The former keeps my stylesheets working that are stored within my includes folder and the latter allows me to specify a custom 404 page (which is necessary given the way my pages load dynamically). Thanks!