# Get file from distant PC

Tags: php, networking, raspberry-pi

I have a PC connected to a Raspberry via an Ethernet network. In Raspberry there is the file Stb.php in directory /var/www/ the IP of Raspberry is 192.168.1.15.
I like to use a function in file Stb.php named `sendScreenCommand` from my server which installed in my PC. 
Here is my code but it is not working:

```
include 'http://192.168.1.15/Stb.php';
$command="mkdir /flash/Resources/resources"
sendScreenCommand($command);
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Can you explain more clearly what  results or error message you get when you try this? Can you be clearer how you are accessing this from the PC?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `allow_url_include` in your php.ini configuration file.

Doing this is strongly discouraged, as it can present serious security risks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it like that. The path you are using is a url on a web-server and according to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> This is not strictly speaking the same thing as including the file and
>   having it inherit the parent file's variable scope; the script is
>   actually being run on the remote server and the result is then being
>   included into the local script.

So your php file is being parsed / executed on the Raspberry and all you get back are the results so there are not functions to execute.

Unless `Stb.php` outputs php code of course, but that seems very unlikely from what I understand from the question...

If this is on a local network, you could make it work if you can mount the file-system of the Raspberry on your pc so that you can use a file path like for example:

```
include '/mnt/Raspberry/Stb.php';
```

(assuming something like linux or OSX, on Windows it would be a bit different)

Comment: Solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752783/including-php-file-from-another-server-with-php