# How do I execute a PHP file on another server?

Tags: php, file, server, web

I have an HTML form on one server and I want to link it to a PHP file on another server. The other servers that has the PHP also has a database with files in it.

All my servers are free hosting accounts. I am starting my own business and I am using free hosting sites until I generate profits.

I need to link my MAIN.php file to other servers. Should I create a DatabaseFORM.php file in my MAIN server to send files to the other servers?

IF so, how would I send to all the servers from the DatabaseFORM.php file?

How do I execute PHP files on other serves from my MAIN.php file?

ok i realized that the PHP.ini file must allow server communication between php files from server to server.

will i be able to create a form on c+ to log into my servers and post to each server from my main form on my laptop?
I think if i have the master form access each webpage with the form then i can have the master form, enter the values in each form and send.

is this possible?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you have data in a server and you want to submit to another server?

Comment: You may want to give a look to that subject : [including php file from another server with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752783/including-php-file-from-another-server-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

To execute php file on other server simply use

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/something.php');
```

and if you want to show this data to user `return` them.

Comment: Thank you guys, i got it, and all is working properly