# PHP and MySQL connection method

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection

I have a `.php` file called `db_conn.php` which establishes a connection to the database. Here is the code of the file.

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "password";
  $dbname = "db_name";
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: ");
  }
  else{
  }
?>
```

When I need to do some database operations from some other file for example from a `login.php` file, what I do is I use the `include_once()` function providing the location to the `db_conn.php` as the parameter. I do the same for another PHP file which needs DB access. I have a few doubts regarding this practice/method.

**1.** Is it okay to do this since I use the `include_once()` function and call the DB connection script more than once? Will it open new connections each time? If yes how should this be implemented?

**2.** If someone tries to include the file from an external domain by using `include_once("www.mywebsite.com/php/db_conn.php")` will they be able to execute DB queries on my DB?

Comment: Why not use `if(!defined('NO_ACCESS')) die('No script kiddies please');` & then use `define('NO_ACCESS', 0);` in your file before you `require_once`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is it okay to do this since I use the include_once() function and call the DB connection script more than once? Will it open new
>      connections each time? If yes how should this be implemented?

Yes, this is fine. Since you're using `include_once`, PHP will automatically recognize that it's already included the file, skip the second call, and you'll only get one connection. I'd recommend changing this to `require_once` however, since you want the script to immediately fail if the included file isn't found.

> 2. If someone tries to include the file from an external domain by using include_once("www.mywebsite.com/php/db_conn.php") will they be
>      able to execute DB queries on my DB?

Generally, no. Anybody requesting that URL will just get a blank page. However, best practice is to put library files like this outside of the web server's document root. For example:

```
/path/to/project
    /public
        index.php
    /lib
        db_conn.php
```

Here, you'd point your web server to `/path/to/project/public` and then in your `index.php`, you'd do something like:

```
require_once '../lib/db_conn.php';
```

Or maybe:

```
ini_set('include_path', '/path/to/project/lib');
require_once 'db_conn.php';
```

This way, your own code can refer to the PHP files in `/lib` but they can not be requested directly via the web server.

Answer (score 0):

> **1.** *Is it okay to do this since I use the include_once() function and call the DB connection script more than once? Will it open new
>   connections each time? If yes how should this be implemented?*

You should be using `require_once("db_conn.php");`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Here are the differences between `include(), include_once(), require()` and `require_once()`

[Difference between require, include, require_once and include_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-require-once-and-include-once)

> **2.** *If someone tries to include the file from an external domain by using include_once("www.mywebsite.com/php/db_conn.php") will they be
>   able to execute DB queries on my DB?*

If this setting is disabled/not allowed by default in most web servers (php.ini) so you can not use the `include` to include the files from  a remote addresss for **security reasons**.

If you still want to allow **inclusion** of remote files, the directive [`allow_url_include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) must be set to `On` in php.ini

But again it is a bad practice, in a security-oriented point of view ; and, so, it is generally disabled (I've never seen it enabled, actually)

**If you want to read the contents of a remote file though**, you can use the **[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)** function instead **BUT** this will be returned as pure HTML markup code, there won't be any **server-side** code.

Reference: [including php file from another server with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752783/including-php-file-from-another-server-with-php)