# How do I include PHP include files in Xampp?

Tags: php, xampp

I have installed Xampp, and I'm accessing a test page with this url: http://localhost/php8/test.php

test.php has the following code in it which works fine in production.

```
<?php include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/nav-blue.php"); ?>
```

However, when I call this url http://localhost/php8/test.php, I have the following error:

> Warning: include(C:/xampp/htdocs/includes/nav-blue.php): Failed to
> open stream: No such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\php8\test.php on line 1
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
> 'C:/xampp/htdocs/includes/nav-blue.php' for inclusion
> (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\php8\test.php on
> line 1

So my question is how can I call include files in my php page on Xampp? Somehow the domain name needs to be implemented somwhere to get the full path e.g. mydomain.com/includes/nav-blue.php

Comment: Does the file `c:/xampp/htdocs/includes/nav-blue.php` exist? If not what is the correct path?Please update the question to clarify.

Comment: @AD7six — The full path easy to work out from the last paragraph

Comment: but where do I have to add the mydomain.com in Xampp?

Comment: `where do I have to add the mydomain.com in Xampp`...what do you mean? This has nothing to do with your error. And you can't really host a domain on your local machine, that would be something you'd do on an internet-facing server. `http://localhost/` is correct for accessing a local development server.

Comment: So your code `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/nav-blue.php"` is causing you the error... it would appear that your document root is `C:/xampp/htdocs`, but it seems you don't have a file called `includes/nav-blue.php` that folder. That's what the error is telling you. It's unclear what that has to do with domain names?

Comment: ok thanks I thought I could call external files :-)

Comment: Do you mean you want to `include` something from another website? Why? And obviously that won't work anyway because you generally don't have access to another server's filesystem, unless you can mount it across the network. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752783/including-php-file-from-another-server-with-php

Comment: `The full path easy to work out from the last paragraph` @Quentin well, not really. At least not without making some assumptions/guessing.